# How to retry blocking IO Action when timeout?

Tags: haskell, io, retry-logic

How does one deal with a blocking `IO` action in Haskell? How can I put this `IO` action inside a scope and manage this scope from another method? If the timeout is reached, I would just reinvoke this method. Normally in other languages, I would probably put this in a separate thread and `abort` it if I do not get the result in a configurable time. (The timer being external.)

In my case: I have a number of `retries` and let's say I want to perform an `IO` action with a timeout. How can I place the `IO` action in a timeout-ed scope so that it gets recalled  after the timeout expires, if and only if the number of `retries` is greater 0.

Basically: given our `IO` action like `ioMethod::IO String` (I have not looked yet in the socket library for Haskell), we'll assume its a black box,

```
module Retry where

import IOExternal(ioMethod)

retryFunc :: Int -> IO String
retryFunc retries=do
            msg<-retry 5 100 IOExternal 
            return msg

retry :: Int -> Int -> IOExternal -> IO String
retry retries timeout ioMethod = go retries timeout "" where
        go 0       timeout ioMethod  msg =
                    if msg=="" then return "Max Retries reached" 
                               else return msg

        go retries timeout ioMethod  msg counter
               = gogo retries timeout counter msg  where
                     gogo retries timeout 0 msg = return ""
                     gogo retries timeout counter msg
                        = ioMethod>>=gogo retries timeout counter-1
```

I do not know how to model this last condition/line.

**P.S** I am not yet familiar with threading in Haskell (beginner here) and I do think that the timeout-ed scope should perform in different thread,and somehow I need to check it from my main program, and either recall it (if retries>0) or end the main method.

Comment: Please re-insert the code with proper indentation. Note you can just paste the code from your `.hs` file, select it, and press `ctrl`-`k`.

Comment: I reformatted it and made some parameter simplifications.

Comment: Erm, the indentation is still wrong. Imports and top-level definitions must not be indented.

Comment: [retry](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/retry-0.7.6.3/docs/Control-Retry.html#v:retrying) package provides retry logic implementation if you want to avoid writing it by hand. There is also [timeout](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/System-Timeout.html) combinator in `base` if you just want to limit `IO` action with timeout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [timeout](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/System-Timeout.html#v:timeout) to add a timeout to any blocking call, and simple recursion for retries:

```
retry :: Int -> Int -> IO a -> IO (Maybe a)
retry 0 _ _ = return Nothing
retry numRetries microseconds action = do
    result <- timeout microseconds action
    case result of
        Nothing -> retry (numRetries-1) microseconds action
        Just a  -> return (Just a)
```

Do read the documentation for caveats about FFI stuff, though.